# SQL two left joins result only data from first table

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my query:

```
select dr.*, v.hash, d.* from directory d 
left join directory_relations dr on d.id = dr.directory_id 
left join videos v on dr.video_id = v.id
```

This is result:
[image]
Result is only 5 rows, but in directory_relations is 6 record.
Table: **directory_relations**
[image]

Table: **directory**

[image]

Look likes miss data about VIDEO. but i don't know why because in VIDEO table row with id 14059 exists.

Comment: You don't have a row in `d` with an `id` of 9.

Comment: can you show us videos  table

Comment: If directory is the parent table, then you should not have a child record in directory_relations that has no directory record. Your data model seems to be messed up and you have a data integrity problem. If directory_relations is the parent table, then your join is wrong and you should join to directory relations left join directory left join video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first `left join` is preserving all the rows from `directory` table, not the ones from `directory_relations`. To preserve both you'd need a `full outer join` instead, but MySQL doesn't support that operation. To emulate it you can write your query like

```
select  t1.*, v.hash
from    (
            select  dr.*, d.id as d_id, d.name, d.user_id
            from    directory d 
            left join
                    directory_relations dr
            on      d.id = dr.directory_id 
            union
            select  dr.*, d.id as d_id, d.name, d.user_id
            from    directory_relations dr 
            left join
                    directory d
            on      d.id = dr.directory_id 
        ) t1
left join
        videos v
on      t1.video_id = v.id
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'full outer join
        directory_relations dr
on      d.id = dr.directory_id

Comment: You're right, wasn't thinking about MySQL not supporting full outer join. Now it should work

Comment: Duplicate column name 'id'

Comment: You will need to give an alias to one of the `id` columns, either the one from `d` or to the one from `dr`. I edited my answer

Comment: The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Comment: Are you sure the directory table only has those three columns?

Comment: I edited my questions anyways, now it should be more robust (will work even if the directories table has more columns)

Comment: has two more columns (5 columns)

Comment: Unknown column 'v.v.hash' in 'field list'

Comment: What about using your imagination? That's a typo in the first row of code, it's obviously `v.hash`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141365/discussion-between-jensej-and-stefano-zanini).

Answer (score 0):

You are using a LEFT JOIN that will return all rows from the left table, and all rows from the right table that have a match. That's why ID=9 won't be returned: because it's present on the table on the right, but there's no directory with ID=0 on the left table.

You might want to switch the order of the tables... or you might want to add directory with an ID=0 on the directory table, but which solution is better depends on the logic of your database.